# Twilio Chat websocket closes after long idle time

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-programmable-chat

I'm writing a chat app using Twilio's Programmable Chat JS SDK. The app works fine, but I noticed after some long time (maybe 30+ minutes) where the browser tab is inactive, when I return to the browser tab the websocket connection is closed. These are the messages that appear in the console after switching to the inactive browser tab:

```
WebSocket connection to 'wss://tsock.us1.twilio.com/v3/wsconnect' failed: Error 
in connection establishment: net::ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED

twilio-chat.min.js:204 WebSocket connection to 
'wss://tsock.us1.twilio.com/v3/wsconnect' failed: WebSocket is closed before 
the connection is established.
```

1) Is this normal? Does it have to do with the fact that I'm still on the Twilio Free Plan?
2) How to manage socket connections in these cases? Also if the internet connection is lost then reestablished, how to ensure the web socket reconnects?

I tried to listen to the `connectionStateChanged` event as per the SDK docs here:
http://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/chat/releases/3.2.0/docs/Client.html#event:connectionStateChanged
but when the user's device is sleeping (e.g. laptop in sleep mode) the event will not fire and therefore the socket will close.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Was a known bug from Twilio. Solved by updating to the JS SDK 3.2.